# Why can't I seem to merge shapeless records with Options correctly?

Tags: scala, shapeless

If I merge two records as follows:

```
case object Key
val a = (Key ->> Option.empty[String]) :: HNil
val b = (Key ->> Option("plif")) :: HNil
val c = a.merge(b)
```

Then as we would expect we have that `b == c`. However, if I use a plain string instead of `None` for `a` then this isn't true anymore:

```
case object Key
val a = (Key ->> "pluf") :: HNil
val b = (Key ->> Option("plif")) :: HNil
val c = a.merge(b)
```

In this case `c` turns out to be: `"pluf" :: Some("plif") :: HNil` and `c.keys` is `Key :: Key :: HNil`. What gives?

I'm using Shapeless 2.1 if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that the types being merged have to be congruent to merging. That is, they must be of the same type. In the first case you have 2 `Option[String]` types while in the 2nd case, you have an `Option[String]` and a `String`.

Looking at the code (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/records.scala#L157-L192) and working through the implicit logic to understand how `Merger` works:

1. We can see that the `implicit` with the highest priority (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/records.scala#L179-L191) prefers that the value types match between records. It substitutes the value in the merged record output.
2. The lower priority `implicit`
   (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/records.scala#L162-L167)
   is only activated if the types don't match, appending the head and
   then iteratively traversing down into the record's structure.
3. Finally, in the case of `HNil` it just appends whatever remains after all other operations in the second record to the first. That is, if they don't match in size, it takes whatever else is available.